# DataFrame not saving correct value

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I am working on a large dataset , where i need to see if next row value in same column is greater then current value. Then save 1 or -1. So if current row in col d is 1 and next value in same col is 2, then it save 1 on a new column ('e) in same row and same dataframe. Problem is it always save one single value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
mask = df1.applymap(lambda x: x <-0.7)
df1 = df1[-mask.any(axis=1)]
sLength = len(df1['a'])


rwno=0
PrevClose=[]
for index,row  in df1.iterrows():
     Close=row.iloc[3]
     PrevClose.append(Close)
     rwno+=1


print df1
rwno=1  
for index,row  in df1.iterrows():
    NxtDaySpy=0
    if rwno < len(df1.index) :   
         NextClose=PrevClose[rwno]
         Close=row.iloc[3]
         df1['e']=pd.Series((NextClose-Close)/abs(NextClose-Close), index=df1.index)

    rwno+=1


print df1.head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you had a data frame with just one column for simplicity.

```
np.random.seed(14)  # so you can reproduce
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 1), columns=['a'])
df.head()

---------
 a
---------
 1.331587
 1.331587
 0.715279
-1.545400
-0.008384
 0.621336
```

You can use `shift()` to lag (or lead) your data.

```
df['a_new'] = df.shift(periods=1).fillna(0.0)
df.head()

---------------------
 a           a_new
---------------------
 1.331587    0.000000
 0.715279    1.331587
-1.545400    0.715279
-0.008384   -1.545400
 0.621336   -0.008384
```

and then use list comprehension to get your `1`'s and `-1`'s.

```
df['a_flags'] = [1 if x > y else -1 for x, y in zip(df.a, df.a_new)]
df.head()

-------------------------------
 a           a_new       a_flag
-------------------------------
 1.331587    0.000000    1
 0.715279    1.331587   -1
-1.545400    0.715279   -1 
-0.008384   -1.545400    1
 0.621336   -0.008384    1
```

Comment: I used this logic in little different way but this worked perfect.